# Cancel deployment on TFS programmatically via C#

Tags: c#, tfs, release, tfs-sdk

I want to abort running deployment via TFS API with C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.NET client libraries for Azure DevOps Services (and TFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts).

This code snippet cancel a release:

```
string projectName = "";
int releaseId = 1;
string collectionUri = "";

VssCredentials creds = new VssClientCredentials();
creds.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();

// Connect to Azure DevOps Services
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), creds);
ReleaseHttpClient releaseClient = connection.GetClient<ReleaseHttpClient>();

ReleaseUpdateMetadata releaseUpdateMetadata = new ReleaseUpdateMetadata()
{
    Comment = "Abandon the release",
    Status = ReleaseStatus.Abandoned
};

// Abandon a release
WebApiRelease updatedRelease = releaseClient.UpdateReleaseResourceAsync(releaseUpdateMetadata, projectName, releaseId ).Result;
```

More details and examples you can find [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples).

Comment: Thanks @Shayki, It is exactly what I've looking for.